# What do these Dash-to-Dock click-actions actually do?

Tags: ubuntu-dock, 21.10, dash-to-dock

What do the following options for the click behavior for Ubuntu Dock (i.e. Dash-to-Dock) do?

- `'minimize-or-overview'`
- `'previews'`
- `'minimize-or-previews'`
- `'focus-or-previews'`
- `'focus-minimize-or-previews'`

I checked the [Dash-to-Dock GitHub page](https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock), but I couldn't find documentation on these settings.

These are some of the options available in gsettings...

```
gsettings range org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action
```

Comment: The best you can do is try these settings. The actual behaviour of clicking a button depends on whether the appliction is already opened, whether a window of the application is already in focus or not, and whether the application has one or more windows open.